# Is there a difference between 患者 and 病人?

Tags: difference

Both 患者 and 病人 can mean patient. When would you prefer one over the other?

Comment: jukuu's samples seem to suggest that particular ailments/diseases can be  used attributively with both   **患者**  : 休克患者,精神病患者，霍乱患者，肺脓肿患者,慢性病患者,癌症患者
**病人**  :肥胖病人,糖尿病人,心血管病人,晚期病人, but 病人 seems
to be used more often w/o mentioning any particular disease, and  has greater usage frequency,

Comment: Somewhat like the difference between "job" and "career".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 患 = contracted (of disease); 者= the one who
>
> **患者** = the one who contracted (disease) = **patient**

- The term 患者 describes 'a patient of a specific disease'. For example: '癌症**患者**' (cancer **patient**), '皮膚病**患者**'(skin disease **patient**).
- We cannot use '患者' without referencing the disease

> **病人** = **sick person**/ **patient**

- The term **病人** is a general term for '**sick people/ patient**'. You can use this term to designate a unwell person without mentioning the disease. For example "病人需要更多的休息" (sick people/ patients need more rest). *-*doesn't matter what kind of sickness*
- It can be used interchangeably with 患者 when referring a **patient** of a particular disease. For example 癌症**病人** (cancer **patient**), 皮膚病**病人**(skin disease **patient**)

Comment: re:"We cannot use '患者' without referencing the disease",   in
the sense that 患者 implies some disease which however need not be mentioned, maybe it is a matter of degree, mentioning disease more likely with 患者 ):  cf. jukuu for 患者，

Comment: The name of a  particular disease usually accompany the term 患者. However, You don't need to mention the sickness in the same sentence, if it was mentioned previously in the same conversation.